# Como faço para usar a função IN do SQL no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Fiz esse código que confronta duas bases, uma para saber se o funcionário logou no servidor de login/logoff e se o funcionário é do pré (temos pré e pós) mas não consigo usar a função `IN` para comparar as bases

```
<?php
include 'conexao.php';
include 'conexaoSmart241.php';
$iniMes1 = date('2021/m/d 08:00:00');
$gestao4 = 'MARINA GONCALVES DA SILVA SENA';
$qLogados = pg_query($conexao241, "SELECT distinct nome FROM public.smart_login_agentes WHERE datahora_ini >= '$iniMes1' AND nome_gestor LIKE '$gestao4'");
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($qLogados)) {
  $logados4 = $row['nome'];
    $logados44 = $logados4 ."," .$logados44  ;
}
$string = "$logados44";
$qLogados = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT distinct vendedor FROM tbl_equipes2 WHERE gestor LIKE '$gestao4' AND vendedor IN($string)");
$lista1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qLogados);
$logados45 = $lista1['vendedor'];
?>
```

Estou usando de forma errada?
Preciso transformar em string, array ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Considerando que é `vendedor IN($string)`, não deveria colocar aspas simples nos valores? Exiba a segunda consulta ao invés de executá-la no banco ou utilize alguma ferramenta de depuração e verá que a SQL que está construindo está errada por isso.

Comment: Atenção que o código em cima está potencialmente a expor-se a `SQL Injection`. Ao usar os valores provinientes da DB sem os validar é possível explorar os valores introduzidos para fazer coisas nefastas. A melhor forma de demonstrar é através da [sátira](https://xkcd.com/327/)